# How to use task<T> in a view component MVC .netcore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@model Task<SocialManager.Model.MSEData>

<article class="social_list" style="display: inline-block">
    <select id="social_list_lb">
        <option value="None">-- Select --</option>
            @foreach (var ll in Model.SocialListViewModel)
            {  
                 <option value="@ll.ListName">@ll.ListName</option>
            } 


    </select>
    <button class="add_field" data-field-key="@Model.Id">ADD</button>
</article>


public async Task<MSEData> GetMSEDataByValue(long id)
{
    var v = MSEData.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    var t = TrioData.Where(u => u.MSEDataId == v.Id).ToList();

    v.TrioField = t;    
    v.SocialListViewModel = SocialListDataContext.SocialListViewModelList2;
    await GetXMLData();

    v.TrioShows = vm.trio;

    return v;
}

public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{          
      var MSEDatas =  _MSEData.GetMSEDataByValue(SocialController.holdVal);
      return View(MSEDatas);
}

VIZTrioMse vm = new VIZTrioMse();
public async Task GetXMLData()
{

    string serviceDocUri = "http://127.0.0.1:5555";
    await vm.GetShows(serviceDocUri);
}
```

I have changed my model From just `MSEData` to `Task<-MSEData->` but I am getting this error message on: `Model.SocialListViewModel`

> 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'TrioShows' and no
>   extension method 'TrioShows' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Task' could be found

I am also get this for all my other properties apart from Id.

Comment: Why is your model a `Task<SocialManager.Model.MSEData>` instead of a `SocialManager.Model.MSEData`?  How do you plan to *await* that task in the view?

Comment: You *don't* need tasks in a view. The view is responsible for displaying things, not processing. Processing should be done by the *controller*. Your model should be the *result* of a task, ie `SocialManager.Model.MSEData`, not the task that may or may not produce the data

Comment: Please post your action code. It looks like you returned a task instead of its results. You should have a line like `var result=await WhateverLoadsTheDataAsync(); return View(result);`

Comment: The combination of controller and view don't make sense here.  `v` is not a `Task<>`, otherwise this won't compile.  If `v` is an instance of `MSEData` then your model is `MSEData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `Task<>` as your model.  Use the model itself:

```
@model SocialManager.Model.MSEData
```

You shouldn't be sending a *task* to your view.  You should be *awaiting* the task and sending the *result* to your view.

**Edit:** Given the controller action you've posted, `v` can't be an instance of `Task<>` or that code wouldn't compile at all.  `v` is an instance of `MSEData`, so your model *should* be `MSEData`.

**Edit again, since you keep changing the question:**  I'm not 100% familiar with this:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{    
    var MSEDatas =  _MSEData.GetMSEDataByValue(SocialController.holdVal);
    return View(MSEDatas);
}
```

But it seems that you should be *awaiting* that `async` operation:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{    
    var MSEDatas = await _MSEData.GetMSEDataByValue(SocialController.holdVal);
    return View(MSEDatas);
}
```

also use InvokeAsync() instead of Invoke()

Comment: @TânNguyễn: Does he have to return `View(v)` in .NET Core?  Seems like that would present itself as an entirely different error message which he hasn't mentioned.  Second, this entire answer addresses the error message.  His model should be of type `MSEData`, which presumably *does* contain a definition for `TrioShows` and his other properties.

Comment: The Edit I sent you works but not when I refresh the page. I have tried the answer above but I get : InvalidOperationException: Method 'Invoke' of view component 'SocialManager.ViewComponents.AddMSEDataViewComponent' cannot return a Task.

Comment: @Decoder94: The only attempted edit I've seen on this answer was an attempt to use `async void`.  I honestly can't think of a worse suggestion than to do that.  As for the view component, I guess I'm not entirely familiar with how that works.  But ultimately you need to return an instance of your model to the view.  *Not* a `Task<>`.

Comment: With the edit I sent you where I changed task to void when I first run the app I get all result but if I Refresh the Page I get 4;

Comment: @Decoder94: Don't use `async void`.  If this answer is no longer helpful then I can certainly delete it, but editing any answer to recommend the use of `async void` is nothing short of vandalizing the answer.